# Feasibility of a Reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, entropy

I understand for a reaction to be feasible, $\Delta$H needs to be negative and $\Delta$S positive. But in terms of Gibbs free Energy Change, without considering kinectic factors, If $\Delta$H is negative and $\Delta$S is negative the reaction is not feasible at a certain temperature but for a higher temperature the reaction can occur.

Secondly with $\Delta$H as a positve value and $\Delta$S as a postive value, this reaction is also not feasible but with a certain high enough temperature the reaction occurs. I think this because $\Delta$G is always dependent on T$\Delta$S and if $\Delta$S is positive then $\Delta$G will be negative which means it is feasible.

Is this correct?

Comment: The answer would have bigger value for you, if you elaborate in the question, why you think it may be right and why you think it may be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by a bigger value? A bigger value for Delta G?

Comment: Bigger value figurally. Like yes/no and why > yes/no only.

Comment: $\Delta H$ can be positive if $\Delta S$ is negative enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the real dictator of whether a reaction is spontaneous or not is the sign of the change in total entropy, as per the second law of thermodynamics. All the specific conditions we memorize ($\Delta{A}<0$ for constant T,V; $\Delta{G}<0$ for constant T,P) are just convenient simplifications of this requirement, as it's very difficult to control for/measure the change in entropy of the surroundings. For example, for a reaction to be spontaneous at fixed temperature and pressure, the change in the system's Gibbs free energy must be negative. This, in turn, can be derived from the requirement that a spontaneous process result in a negative total change in entropy.

Now, onto your question! For a reaction to be feasible, we only need to consider the sign of $\Delta{S}$, where S is the total entropy. What you are referring to as S is the entropy of just the system (and not of the surroundings). This alone is not enough information to decide whether a reaction is spontaneous for any circumstance. If we do not have information about the total entropy change, then we must rely on these simplifying cases. At constant T and P,
$\Delta{G}=\Delta{H}-T\Delta{S}$ must be negative for a spontaneous reaction.
∆H could be positive, as long as T∆S were larger in magnitude (and positive). Conversely, ∆S could be negative, as long as T∆S were smaller in magnitude than ∆H.

Your overall sentiment about temperature dependence is correct, but the statements about feasibility is not (as described above).